# Mysql slow query log always include "# Time:"

Tags: mysql, performance, slow-log

I am trying to parse the mysql slow log with logstash so it's important that the format is consistent. I have noticed that if statements execute at the same time, the line `# Time: yymmdd` is only logged once (see example below). I looked at the setting [mysqld_log-long-format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-long-format) however this setting is deprecated and supposedily the default. I have not enabled the log-short-format option.

Is there any setting that can enforce the `Time` field to either always show, or always not show? I don't actually need the information since there is also a `timestamp`, I just need the output to be consistent.

```
# Time: 150419  6:00:43
# User@Host: web[web] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 7.730519  Lock_time: 0.000070 Rows_sent: 167620  Rows_examined: 167620
SET timestamp=1429416043;
SELECT /*!40001 SQL_NO_CACHE */ * FROM `messages`;
# Time: 150419  6:00:45
# User@Host: web[web] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 3.480173  Lock_time: 0.000101 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1429416045;
INSERT INTO user (lastupdated, fk_id, user_id) ..
# User@Host: web[web] @ localhost []
# Query_time: 3.388204  Lock_time: 0.000133 Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 0
SET timestamp=1429416045;
INSERT INTO user (lastupdated, fk_id, user_id) ..
```

The logstash config I'm using looks like this - see [logstash multiline codec](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html)

```
input { 
  file {
     path => "mysql-slow.log"
     codec => multiline {
        pattern => "^# Time" 
        negate => true
        what => previous
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Not hard to keep a running variable in your parser with the current value of time. I guess it depends on what your parser is written in.

Comment: Logstash is mainly using regex - http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-multiline.html

Comment: @aland Have you tried tutorials like http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/adding-mysql-slow-query-logs-to-logstash/ already? The idea is to use the timestamp, and not the time the query was logged.

Comment: @jynus yes I had based my config from that blog and I'm using timestamp for a timestamp, I'm using the line 'Time' as an anchor to mark the start of a new log event - but it seems he has recently edited it so that the pattern is based on the 'User' line rather than 'Time'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of things have changed in the slowlog over the versions.  Discover the inconsistencies and code to them!

`# Time` (and maybe some other things) are specified only when they change.

In 5.7.2 Time will include microseconds.  This is one of many syntax changes that have happened over the years -- be careful.  Percona and MariaDB also have different things that can show in the SlowLog.

Query time used to be just an integer.

Comment: Is the format of the slow query log documented for each version?

Comment: Ha ha.  Not that I have ever seen.  In my previous job, I devised a parser that worked for hundreds of machines, dozens of versions.  Every few months, I would need to tweak it for a new change.  It was a custom Perl script, based on [mysqldumpslow](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldumpslow.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well this answer doesn't make much sense when I can't add a `logstash` tag, but I've changed the multiline input codec to anchor each pattern to a `# User` line as the `# Time` line is not always present.

I can't find any way to change this setting in MySQL but I'll leave this question open for a while in case it is possible and someone knows.